# iOS 5 objective C orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios5, orientation-changes

I am learning to dvelop applications for iPhone on iOS5. I have no prior experience with any other version. I wanted to support multiple orientations and i have been searching a lot lately. But i have not found a solution.

1) I could use a navigation controller, which would push and pop view controllers in and out of the stack according to the orientation changes. But that would mean that i'll have to make 2 copies of everything, one for landscape and one for potrait.

2) I make a new landscape view controller. In willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method of potrait view controller I initialize an instance of the landscpe view controller and set it as presentViewController. In landscape VC, i initialize an instance of potrait and do the same. But I think this would just take up more and more memory because this instances are nmot being 'popped' as in the case of navigation controller.
(i have not yet read the memory management guide)

3) There were some things about the resizing of the view. I did really understand this method.

Please suggest what is the method that is generally used and why.

Comment: Do you need  how to set orientation ?

Comment: I want that my sreen should adjust to orientation changes. My views should not move above or below the screen. The third solution I mentioned is now working for me http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_5_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling

But I think there might be places when this won't work. That is why creating a separate controller has also been considered as an option.

Comment: You mean LandScape and portrait ?

Comment: yes. when the screen size changes from or to landscape to or from portrait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not need to create separate ViewController for Landscape and portrait.

```
If suppose You have a button named btnSample.


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  UIInterfaceOrientation des=self.interfaceOrientation;
  if ((interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)||(interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
    {
```

//Portrait

```
btnSample.frame=CGRectMake(10,10,100,70);

    }
  else
  {
```

//Landscape

```
btnSample.frame=CGRectMake(200,100,100,70);

  }
```

}

Comment: Thanks. I think it will work. But at this time I have made a small app. But there are people who build bigger apps and use separate view controllers for different orientation. Why is that? Do you think it might be needed for applications of a bit larger scale?

Comment: Sure,  app needs Orientation.  landscape and portraits. But large apps like games in Cocos2d that have only One orientation. Landscape or portrait. Please check the code, whether it is working or not . If You are satisfied with this Answer accept it.

Comment: I am sure app needs orientation. But i am talking about the method being used. 'WHY" has the method of creating different view controllers been proposed when change in orientation can be handled by such simple method ?

Comment: Each vieController's Controls orientations have to given the same class itself.

Comment: All controls in each class , Orientation set in that class Only.